# Failed to upload DSYMS file. I have uploaded myapp.app.dSYM zipped file but again it is asking me to upload "Upload missing required dSYMs"

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I have tried uploading dSYMS file , it is showing "Your uploaded files will be processed shortly. Check the dashboard in a few minutes to see crashes that were previously missing." but but still it is asking me to upload even after 2 days. My bitcode is disable.I got this dSYM files using Xcode's app archive.[image]

[image: "]

When I am trying to download it from organizer it is showing "No dSYMs were found for Version 1.8 Build 9.

Comment: same case with me, are your crashlytics dashboard now show error ?

Comment: Not yet. tried everything , don't know where I am lagging :/

Comment: Have you tried bitcode = yes, then download DSYMS from it then reupload ?

Comment: Yes, tried with that too,but no success.
1. By enabling bitcode and downloded the dSYMS from appstore and uploded the same( didn't worked).
2. By uploading the dSYMS by archiving and making zip.(didn't worked)

Comment: @RanuDhurandhar Did you get any solution for this? Even I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: @AnJu I was getting this error due to UUID mismatch, find the DSYM file of matching UUID as of the UUID in dashboard ad then upload the same.
 you can find your Local DSYM file path by running this command in terminal:

mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == <UUID>"

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == <UUID>"` command in your terminal to find the missing dSYM on your Mac and then upload it to crashlytics.

To check the UUID of a dSYM file, using the following command `dwarfdump -u <pathTodSYMFile.dsym>`